# Why does write() method returns the length of string in IPython/Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I've seen some strange (at least for me) behavior while using write() method in Ipython as well as Jupyter notebook:

```
In [1]: f = open('test.txt','w')
In [2]: f.write("This is the first line")
Out[2]: 22
```

It is actually returning the length of the string which I wrote in the file.

*I am bit curious about this behavior. Can someone please explain why this happens?*

Comment: because it's in the specification of the `write` method maybe? and when you run this in an interactive interpreter you always get the return values (unless it's `None`)

Comment: [`write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=write#io.TextIOBase.write)

Comment: It does exactly what it is documented to do so what is your actual question?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Didn't actually look at the documentation carefully. Apologies!!!

Comment: You can suppress that kind of display with `;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something specific to IPython.

The [`write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=write#io.TextIOBase.write) method returns the number of characters written. 
The reason you are seeing this is because you are using an interpreter.

Comment: It was a silly question out of negligence! Anyways thanks for pointing towards the documentation.